# jQuery/Javascript - get tomorrow at 12:55 date as string

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, date

In PHP i have the following to get tomorrow at 12:55's string:

```
$date_string = ''.date('F').' '.date('j').', '.date('Y').' 12:55';
```

Which if called today would output:

```
July 22, 2014 12:55
```

I need to now get this in pure jquery/javascript and not rely on PHP

How can i do this exact same string?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: Please do not try to do date manipulation by yourself. Date handling is a slippery slope (offsets, timezones, leap years…) and you *will* eventually get into a pitfall when doing more intricate stuff. Please use a proper library, such as [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var date = new Date(); // now

date.setHours(12);
date.setMinutes(55);
date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1); // add one day
```

To get the string you want, you'd have to do something like

```
var months = ['January', 'February' ... etc];

var dateString = months[ date.getMonth() ] + ' ' + 
                 date.getDate() + ', ' + 
                 date.getFullYear() + ' ' + 
                 date.getHours() + ':' + 
                 date.getMinutes();
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/n982S/)